# How can I mix 2 lists in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I have a list, for example: `{Daniel,Michael,Kate}`, and another one: `{Daniel,Michael,Kate}`. What I want is to make a third list, for example: `{Daniel-Kate,Kate-Michael,Michael-Daniel}`. I want to mix them to make a new list with their elements inter-mixed? I tried this:

```
int start2;

//do a check here
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
    start2 = random.nextInt(lista2.size() - 0) + 0;
    if (lista2.get(start2).equals(lista.get(i))) {
        i--;
    } else {
        listaParejas.add(lista.get(i) + "->" + lista2.get(start2));
        listaSalidos.add(lista2.get(start2));
        lista2.remove(start2);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < listaParejas.size(); i++) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), listaParejas.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Sometimes it crashes, or I always get the same couple. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Collections.addAll(lista, lista2); // Join the 2 lists
Collections.shuffle(lista); // shuffle the result list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks somewhat error-prone to me. It'll be a lot more easy to shuffle both lists first and then take their respective elements one by one, like so:

```
Collections.shuffle(list1);
Collections.shuffle(list2);

for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()); i++) {
    list3.add(list1.get(i) + "-" + list2.get(i));
}
```